# Is it possible to make communication in audio or video using Core SignalR

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I am using signalR with ASP.NET Core 2.1 to send and receive messages from server-to-client or client-to-server even I also used streaming channel to send long message in chunks greater than 30kb from client to server.

But now I am wondering is it possible that I can make communication between server and client using voice or video?

I checked WebRTC is giving the solution for my requirement but as I am already using SignalR so I am looking for the solutions using SignalR for the websocket transport.

Comment: I think it depends on how the data is sent to the server, what data type do you send?

Comment: @MasterYoda right now for text message communication is in json format and for big data in base64 string chunk.

Comment: Take a look at [this link](https://www.skylinetechnologies.com/Blog/Skyline-Blog/February-2013/Peer-to-Peer-Media-Streaming-with-WebRTC-and-Signa) You may need to use a combination of WebRTC and SignalR to achieve this. You need WebRTC to share the media stream and SignalR to send the offer to the peer device. I dont believe you can do this using just SignalR. Remember that SignalR is designed to send out simple signals to devices, not really for sending complex messages.

Comment: But what about transport type? As I am using SignalR for websocket and WebRTC also using websocket then I need to make two connection? one with SignalR and one with WebRTC. Is it even possible?

Comment: I dont think it matters which transport method you use for WebRTC, saying that you could try using Websockets for both WebRTC and SignalR. SignalR is pretty good in that if it cant make the connection using the assigned transport you can specify the fallback transport to use instead e.g. if websockets fail, use server sent events or long polling instead. You would need to check that your browser supports those transports though.

Comment: @ShahzadMirza, do you have a solution yet?  I have a similar question with POC source here `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52518467/streaming-audio-buffer-from-a-web-page-to-c-sharp-google-cloud-speech-to-text-sd`

Comment: @JDeVil I already did it. have a look on [this github repo](https://github.com/Shhzdmrz/OneToOneAudioWebRTC) but your case is different i think so.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Adding answer to my old question as nobody added any response to it.

Yes, it is possible to use signalR core with WebRTC as a signaling server.

[Here is the sample project](https://github.com/Shhzdmrz/SignalRCoreWebRTC) that I created for .NET Core 3.1. Feel free to ask me question related to my approach.

Comment: could you please guide me how to run your sample? thanks so much.